# Return an array of Pairs which have the same length as the input array of Strings. (Java)

Tags: java

I want to create a class that would return an array of pairs that have the same length as the input array of strings.
In addition, the pair should have the first letter of the string and length of the string.

for example;
create(new String[] {"clue", "yay", "neon", "halala"})
should return the array of Pairs
{[’c’,4],[’y’,3],[’n’,4],['h',6]}

So, my input and output would both be arrays. But the output has to be in the form of a pair. Here's what i tried:

```
import java.util.Arrays;



public class Couple {


public static Couple[] create(String[] source){

        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {

            System.out.print("["+","+source.length+"]") ;
        }
        return null;

    }            

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(create(new String[] {"clue", "yay", "neon", "halala"})));

    }

}
```

as it's obvious there are a few errors+ i dont want it to return null. But just for the sake of testing this code, i had to do it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Couple {

    private char firstChar;
    private int length;

    public Couple(char firstChar, int length) {
        this.length = length;
        this.firstChar = firstChar;
    }

    public static Couple[] create(String[] source) {
        Couple[] couples = new Couple[source.length]; // create the array to hold the return pairs

        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            String entry = source[i];
            if (entry != null) {
                couples[i] = new Couple(entry.charAt(0), entry.length());
            } else {
                // What do you want to do if there's a null value?
                // Until you answer this we'll just leave the corresponding Couple null aswell
            }
        }

        return couples;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Couple{" +
                "firstChar=" + firstChar +
                ", length=" + length +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since this question is likely someone's homework (by the way, there's absolutely nothing wrong with that) members of the community prefer helping authors of the questions understand how to do their homework, rather than doing it outright for them. The belief here is that it would be of more long-term benefit to the OPs than giving them code. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I even provided my tried-code before asking others to correct me :)

Comment: public String toString() { return ("["+"\'"+firstChar+"\'"+","+length+"]"); }    i wrote the last bit of code that way as i needed the first character in single quotes. PS: my code isnt appearing the way it should in comments as it appeared in the Q? forgive me for that...just new to the forum. Thanks a ton for all your answers. It really helpmed me :D

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track:

- Rather than returning `null`, you should create an array of pairs, and populate it in the loop. You know the length of the result, because you have the length of the source
- To look at an individual word, use `source[i]`
- To chop off the initial letter of the word use `source[i].charAt(0)`
- To get the length of the word use `source[i].length()`
- The `Couple` class needs two data members - a `char` and an `int`; they should be set in the constructor
- The data members should have getters - `public char getChar()` and `public int getLength()` returning their respective members
- Printing should be done in the `main`, in a loop that walks the returned array of pairs

You should be able to complete the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The hint you probably need it this:

```
Couple[] result = new Couple[source.length];
```

and code a loop to create the `Couple` instances and put them into the `result` array.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Couple {

    public static String[] create(String[] source) {

        String[] temp = new String[source.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {

            if (source[i].length() > 0) {
                String newString = "[" + source[i].charAt(0) + ","
                        + source.length + "]";
                //System.out.print(newString);
                temp[i] = newString;
            } else {
                String newString = "[" + " " + "," + 0 + "]";
                //System.out.print(newString);
                temp[i] = newString;
            }

        }
        return temp;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(create(new String[] { "clue", "yay",
                "neon", "halala"})));

    }

}
```