# Array of strings from array of pairs?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there anyway I could return an array of strings from an array of pairs? I'm guessing it's something to do with hashmap since two values are involved. Any simple example with some explanation would help :)

As pointed out by @dasblinkenlight, if the input is (y,3),(t,2) and I want the output as "yPP","tP" where the string should have the length of the numerical value given. and so after taking the character, the rest of the length is to be filled by P.

Suppose I've got the static method,

```
public static Line[] get(Couple[] temp)
```

I need to complete it so that my main method would produce the following result:

```
get (new Couple[]{new Couple(’e’,4), new Couple(’n’,2)})
```

should return the array of Strings

```
{"ePPP", "nP"}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: What do you mean by "array of pairs"?

Comment: @arshajii I think he means [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18116019/335858), but it would be nice to confirm.

Comment: 'pair' could be wrapped into an object , and then override `toString()` to obtain string representation of object, but your question is not clear, please edit

Answer (score 1):

```
class Pair{
    public Pair(String st1,String st2){
        string1=str;
        string2=str;
    }
    private String string1;
    private String string2;

     // + getters and maybe setters for strings;

}
```

Later  on create simple `Pair[]` and do whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

With a `Pair` class implemented as

```
class Pair {
    private final String s;
    private final int i;

    public Pair(String s, int i){
        this.s = s;
        this.i = i;
    }

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Initialize the `Pair[]` and invoke a converter method as

```
Pair[] pairArr = new Pair[2];

pairArr[0] = new Pair("Y", 3);
pairArr[1] = new Pair("T", 2);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(convertPairsToStrArray(pairArr, "P")));
```

***Output** :*

```
[YPP, TP]
```

Here's a sample converter implementation:

```
private static String[] convertPairsToStrArray(Pair[] pairArr, String padStr) {
    String[] strArr = null;
    if (pairArr != null) {
        strArr = new String[pairArr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pairArr.length; i++) {
            String s = pairArr[i].getS();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (s != null) {
                sb.append(s);
                int j = 0; 
                if ((j = pairArr[i].getI() - s.length()) > 0) {
                    while (j-- > 0) {
                        sb.append(padStr);
                    }
                }
            }
            strArr[i] = sb.toString();
        }
    }
    return strArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like many things, the question contains the answer.
Create a class to hold the pairs.  Add a method, to that class, to produce the desired output.  Here is some code:

Pairzor.java:

```
public class Pairzor
{
    private final static char FILL_CHARACTER = 'P';

    private final char theChar;
    private final int theCount;

    public Pairzor(
        final char newChar,
        final int newCount)
    {
        theChar = newChar;
        theCount = newCount;
    }

    public final String blammy()
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        buffer.append(theChar);
        for (int count = 1; count < theCount; ++count)
        {
            buffer.append(FILL_CHARACTER);
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main
{
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pairzor one = new Pairzor('y', 3);
        Pairzor two = new Pairzor('t', 2);

        System.out.println(one.blammy());
        System.out.println(two.blammy());
    }
}
```